# sonarqube installation incorrect

Tags: sonarqube, installation

Does anyone know where I can find accurate instructions?

TIA

The current documentation and kit do not match.
The documentation (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server#InstallingtheServer-installingWebServerInstallingtheWebServer) says

Edit /conf/sonar.properties

The install does not include that directory:

Directory of C:\sonarqube

```
03/13/2017  08:41 AM    <DIR>          .
03/13/2017  08:41 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/10/2017  04:30 PM             6,680 .cix.yml
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               941 .gitignore
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               825 .travis.yml
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               200 build.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM             1,302 cix.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               389 clock.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               548 cve-false-positives.xml
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               287 debug-server.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               159 enable-organizations.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               204 find-classpath-conflicts.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM                69 format-headers.sh
03/10/2017  04:31 PM    <DIR>          it
03/10/2017  04:30 PM             7,651 LICENSE.txt
03/10/2017  04:30 PM                15 logs.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               171 NOTICE.txt
03/10/2017  04:31 PM    <DIR>          plugins
03/10/2017  04:30 PM            47,255 pom.xml
03/10/2017  04:30 PM             1,141 quick-build.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               467 README.md
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               225 run-db-unit-tests.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               769 run-integration-tests.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM                97 run-perf-tests.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               536 run-upgrade-tests.sh
03/10/2017  04:31 PM    <DIR>          scripts
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          server
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-application
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-check-api
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-colorizer
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-core
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-duplications
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-home
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-markdown
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-plugin-api
03/10/2017  04:34 PM    <DIR>          sonar-plugin-api-deps
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-scanner-engine
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-scanner-engine-shaded
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-scanner-protocol
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-testing-harness
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          sonar-ws
03/13/2017  08:31 AM    <DIR>          sonarqube-master
03/10/2017  04:30 PM                16 start.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               273 stop.sh
03/10/2017  04:35 PM    <DIR>          tests
03/10/2017  04:30 PM               192 third-party-licenses.sh
03/10/2017  04:30 PM             6,269 travis.sh
```

Comment: PS: Those instructions also say The charset of the database has to be set to "UTF-8" and the language (database and user) to "English".  However, MySQL says "There are no case sensitive utf8 collations in MySQL yet other than utf8_bin. "

Answer (score 1):

"the documentation and kit do not match" because you don't have "the kit".

Instead of downloading a released version of SonarQube, which you can do from here: https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/, you appear to have instead cloned [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube). You're welcome to do that of course (it *is* FLOSS), but as you've noticed, the "kit" won't match the docs.